# Set hint text color when unfocused and not empty with Android Material Components TextInputLayout from XML

Tags: android, material-components-android

I want the color of the TextInputLayout hint to be the same as if focused even when the view unfocused but not empty without having to manually set the fitting color programmatically on change.

Comment: have you searched anything ?

Comment: Most similar questions on SO either got no answers or answers not really fitting my case.

Answer (score 1):

```
yourEditText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {          
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if(!hasFocus) {
          if(""+yourEditText.getText.length > 0){  // NOT EMPTY
             // do your task when its unFocused and not null
           }               
        }
        else{
             // do your task when its Focused
           }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

So far my only solution to this problem is to listen for focus change and text change event on the `EditText` and change the `TextInputLayout`s `defaultHintTextColor` attribute according to the `EditText` being empty.

Answer (score 0):

Hey there you can set background selector to achieve this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:color="@color/colorSlate" android:state_focused="false" />
    <item android:color="@color/colorMidnight" android:state_focused="true" />

</selector>
```

Just set this as a background of your edittext